# rx android observable + FileInputStream increases heap memory

Tags: android, heap-memory, observable, rx-android

I am working on uploading a big file to a server on android, using retrofit with rxjava.

I have a big file, and I will read file to a small chunk size of bytes array sequently , then put it to server. after success, I will update progress bar.

But the problem is, In my case, I will read 50 chunks, each chunk size is 6MB. For the first 18 chunks, it works fine, heap memory was allocated 6MB, and progress bar was updated smoothly. But from the 19th chunk, progress will be freeze, and heap size was allocated increasingly by 6MB after each time Observable was created.

Anyway, I still upload file to server successfully.

Here is my code :

```
private static void processUpload(File file, final ProgressUpdater updater) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    sCountSuccess = 0;

    Observable<ResponseBody> responseBodyObservable = Observable.from(sUpload.getUploadChunk())
            .flatMap(new Func1<UploadChunk, Observable<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<ResponseBody> call(UploadChunk uploadChunk) {
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    try {
                        byte[] temp = new byte[chunkSize];
                        bytesRead = inputStream.read(temp);
                        if (bytesRead != -1) {

                            byte[] finalBuffer;
                            if (temp.length > bytesRead)
                            {
                                finalBuffer = Arrays.copyOf(temp, bytesRead);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                finalBuffer = temp;
                            }

                            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(""), finalBuffer);
                            Log.d("UPLOAD_ID", uploadChunk.getUrl());
                            Observable<ResponseBody> responseBodyObservable = sNetworkResources.putVideo(uploadChunk.getUrl(), requestBody);

                            return responseBodyObservable;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("UPLOAD_ERROR", e.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                        if(inputStream != null && bytesRead == -1) {
                            try {
                                inputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    responseBodyObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                        updater.onProgressFinish();
                        commitUpload();
//                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody data) {
                    // update
                    sCountSuccess++;
                    updater.onProgressUpdate(sCountSuccess);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/540) post on the Retrofit GitHub page says if you use the @Multipart annotation on your interface you shouldn't need to chunk the stream yourself:

> Retrofit will stream Multipart part bodies directly to the network so the fact that you send a big body should not cause an OOM unless you are causing it to be buffered somehow.

Your interface could look something like this:

```
@Multipart
@PUT(VIDEO_URL)
Observable<ResponseBody> putVideo(@Url String videoUrl, @Part("file") RequestBody requestBody);
```